# Detecting non-members in sandbox hierarchy in MKS

Tags: version-control, mks-integrity

Is there any way how to see the list of files in MKS Integrity Client which are in the project sandbox hierarchy but not added as a member in the MKS project ?

For example when I create new class inside existing package in the sandbox. What I do now is that I have to go through the sandbox hierarchy, find the correct folder and then manualy find and add new member through "New member wizard". This is very tricky when you create more files in one step - it is very easy to forget some file.

Is there some more convinient way for finding non-members ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a command for that (at least for the command line).

```
si viewnonmembers --sandbox=
```

It takes the same universal options as the other si commands, try

```
si viewnonmembers --help
```

to see them

---

The same command is available in the GUI: Try Sandbox->Views->View Non-Members